# Copy large amount of lines from notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

I have log file, with over one million lines and I use Notepad++ to view data. When I want to extract specific word (which is in a unique sentence in line with dates) and after I do count, I get over 400,000 matches.

Trouble is I can not copy it in Excel with Search/Bookmark/Copy Bookmarked Lines because notepad++ freezes (probably because of data size in memory).

Is there any other alternative solution? Can I use Python script for this?

Comment: It should be fairly easily possible with python, if the sentence is an exact match just check which lines contain it. A one line solution would be something like `with open(file, 'r') as f: lines = [i for i in f.readlines() if 'abcdefg' in i]` to get a list of the matching lines. You could possibly save it as a csv file or something after that to get it in excel.

Comment: To process big text file, I use [gvim](http://www.gvim.org), but is slightly more tolerant than notepad++. When they are really too big, I use Python and eventually convert them to sqlite3 if many processing are expected.

Comment: It's worth getting something like grep to work on Windoes and just stream from a prompt

Answer (score 0):

This should works:

```
lines = open(filepath, 'r').readlines()
for i in range(0,len(lines))
{
    if 'yourstring' in lines[i]:
        print("String found at line "+i+": "+lines[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is large, I'd suggest you to stream-read it instead of using `readlines()` to create a completely unnecessary large list (with at least 1M indices):

```
with open("your_file.ext", "r") as f:
    matched_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f if "search string" in line]
```

Now your `matched_lines` has all the lines that contain your string and you can do whatever else you need to do with it.

Comment: Since after running this i got UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 55: character maps to <undefined>. I added  encoding="utf8" after "r". And now how to put this into pandas dataframe?  From there i know how to do analysis:)